# Transitioning a button into a modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm attempting to expand and transition a button into a modal that's 60% of the height and width of the window when it is clicked. Here's a CodePen of my work so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbNONa. The problem I'm having is that the `position` property can't be transitioned. Both the button and the modal (which is underneath the button) are absolutely positioned inside the button wrapper to make both elements look like one element. When the button is clicked, the modal should expand to a `fixed` position on top of the overlay.

The issue is that the positioning immediately changes from `absolute` to `fixed`, so the modal just looks like it's contracting from the full window size. If you delete the `position: fixed` property on the `#btn-content.active` class, you can see what I'm essentially trying to do. How can I emulate the transition of the `position` property? If that's not possible, how can I have the modal transition to a height and width that are relative to the size of the window? Thank you kindly for your time.

Comment: I'd use `getBoundingClientRect()` to create the fixed element with same size as the existing one, then transition to the full size

Comment: @Markasoftware Thanks, I'll use that for now. I'm still going to try to to find a way with css.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's impossible to have an absolutely positioned element have top and left relative to window